# Create function inside deprecated javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

Currently I have a javascript file structure which seems deprecated to me, inside this function there's an ajax call, and after the ajax call giving response I want to add ajax function, but if I have to define it 1 by 1 for every ajax response type, it will consume a lot of space so I need to make a function which will call this ajax function, but I don't know where to place this function that I will make. here's my code

```
return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Icube_Snap/payment/snap'
    },
    redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,
    afterPlaceOrder: function() {
        $.getScript(js, function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: url.build('snap/payment/redirect'),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var token = data;
                    var methods = [];
                    var methodSnap = $('input[name=snap-method]:checked').val();

                    snap.pay(token, {
                        enabledPayments: methods,
                        onSuccess: function(result) {
                            $.ajax({ // <-- this ajax needs to be inside function with parameter
                                type: 'post',
                                url: url.build('custom/message/post'),
                                cache: false,
                                param: {
                                    id: resut.id,
                                    message: result.message
                                }
                                success: function(data) {

                                }
                            });
                        },
                        onPending: function(result) {
                            $.ajax({ // <-- this ajax needs to be inside function with parameter
                                type: 'post',
                                url: url.build('custom/message/post'),
                                cache: false,
                                param: {
                                    id: resut.id,
                                    message: result.message
                                }
                                success: function(data) {

                                }
                            });
                        },
                        onError: function(result) {
                            $.ajax({ // <-- this ajax needs to be inside function with parameter
                                type: 'post',
                                url: url.build('custom/message/post'),
                                cache: false,
                                param: {
                                    id: resut.id,
                                    message: result.message
                                }
                                success: function(data) {

                                }
                            });
                        },
                        onClose: function() {
                            $.ajax({ // <-- this ajax needs to be inside function with parameter
                                type: 'post',
                                url: url.build('custom/message/post'),
                                cache: false,
                                param: {
                                    id: resut.id,
                                    message: result.message
                                }
                                success: function(data) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added a `successcallback` and an `errorcallback` to the `POST` function. But if you want you can ignore those `functions` and implement the `success` and `error` functionality inside the `function` itself without using callbacks.

```js
return Component.extend({
  defaults: {
    template: 'Icube_Snap/payment/snap'
  },
  redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,
  afterPlaceOrder: function() {
    $.getScript(js, function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url.build('snap/payment/redirect'),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          var token = data;
          var methods = [];
          var methodSnap = $('input[name=snap-method]:checked').val();

          //Define a function to send the POST request here.
          //////////////////////////////////////////////////

          var sendPayment = function(param, successcallback, errorcallback) {
            $.ajax({ // <-- this ajax needs to be inside function with parameter
              type: 'post',
              url: url.build('custom/message/post'),
              cache: false,
              param: {
                id: param.id,
                message: param.message
              }
              success: function(data) {
                successcallback(data);
              },
              error: function(error) {
                errorcallback(error);
              }
            });
          };

          snap.pay(token, {
            enabledPayments: methods,
            onSuccess: function(result) {

              //Call sendPayment method and you can 
              //pass whatever you want.

              sendPayment(result, function() {
                //Call when success
              }, function() {
                //Call when error
              });
            },
            onPending: function(result) {
              sendPayment(result, function() {
                //Call when success
              }, function() {
                //Call when error
              });
            },
            onError: function(result) {
              sendPayment(result, function() {
                //Call when success
              }, function() {
                //Call when error
              });
            },
            onClose: function() {
              sendPayment(result, function() {
                //Call when success
              }, function() {
                //Call when error
              });
            }

          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```